# WooCommerce: Echo product title in checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Hope you guys can help.

I'm working on a `WooCommerce` shop that sells software-plans for 1 product. Therefor I've deactivated the cart-page and made it possible only to have 1 item in the checkout (old items are automaticly removed).

What I need, is too `echo out` the product name in the `"cart"` before the checkout fields.
 **E.g.** "Yaaay, you selected the XXXX-plan!".

I tried to use below code from the `review-order.php`, but no luck.

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form' hook or 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review'  hook to add your Title for product purchased in cart.

Basically

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form','wdm_my_custom_title',10,1);

function wdm_my_custom_title($checkout){
 // code to retrieve item title in cart . And echoing it with the custom title which we need.
}
```

Or

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review','wdm_my_custom_title',10);

function wdm_my_custom_title(){
 // code to retrieve item title in cart . And echoing it with the custom title which we need.
}
```

Use one of the codes as per your requirement of location where the Title needs to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately that put it "inside" the boxes instead of above: [link](http://imgur.com/a/G0f6J)